# I want to store the screenshots in android testing and I'm using expresso

Tags: android, junit, screenshot, ui-automation, androidjunitrunner

Below is the code

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ScreenshotJavaTest {
    // a handy JUnit rule that stores the method name

    @Rule
    public TestName nameRule = new TestName();

    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> activityScenarioRule =
            new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    /**
     * Captures and saves an image of the entire {@link MainActivity} contents.
     */
    @Test
    public void saveActivityBitmap() throws IOException {
        writeToTestStorage(captureToBitmap(onView(isRoot())), getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + nameRule.getMethodName());
    }

    /**
     * Captures and saves an image of the 'Hello world' view.
     */
    @Test
    public void saveViewBitmap() throws IOException {
        writeToTestStorage(captureToBitmap(onView(withText("Hello World!"))), getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + nameRule.getMethodName());
    }

    /**
     * Captures and saves an image of the entire device screen to storage.
     */
    @Test
    public void saveDeviceScreenBitmap() throws IOException {

        writeToTestStorage(takeScreenshot(), getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + nameRule.getMethodName());
    }

}
```

All test cases are running but I am not able to find any screenshots anywhere in the device file manager. So How I will find those screenshots or there are some other ways we can achieve to get
these screenshots in automation testing

---

Answer (score 0):

Cannot speak for real devices, but when using the Android Studio Simulator you can find the screenshots using the Device File Explorer at the following path:

*/storage/emulated/0/googletest/test_outputfiles*

Make sure to add the following line to your gradle file:

`testInstrumentationRunnerArguments useTestStorageService: 'true'`

I've been searching for hours and this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.